# How can I use a pre defined CONSTANT inside an array?

Tags: php

I want the code to look like this:

```
define("CONSTANT","World !!");
$array=array(" Hello CONSTANT");

echo $array[0];
```

And the output to look like this:

```
Hello World !!
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `$array=array(" Hello " . CONSTANT);`

Comment: Concatenation? `$array = array("Hello " . CONSTANT);`

Comment: There are lot of dupes of this question. Have you even made an effort to search them on SO?

Comment: `array("Hello {$constant('CONSTANT')}");` should also work. Even though I prefer string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a constant inside an array, simple put it without the quotes:

```
$array=array(" Hello ".CONSTANT);
```

Read here for more informations: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php.